# Transforming lambda expression to simple function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm curious if it is possible to avoid lambda expressions in the following case.

For example using lambda expression I can simple define a function that returns a lambda exp.

```
def square_fun(a,b,c):
   return lambda x: a*x**2 + b*x + c
```

After we can call it using:

```
f = square_fun(1,2,3)

f(1) # here x = 1
```

How can I get the same behaviour avoiding lambda expression?

for example, square_fun must return another function

```
def square_fun(a,b,c):
   return f...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python you can define a function inside another function, so the following snippet should give you the same behavior:

```
def square_fun(a, b, c):
    def result(x):
        return a*x**2 + b*x + c
    return result

f = square_fun(1, 2, 3)
print(f(1))
# Should print 6
```

So, I'll try to explain what's going on here:

1. In the line `f = square_fun(1, 2, 3)`, `f` will actually be mapped to the internal function (aka. `result`)
2. Please note that `return result` does not have the `()` at the end, hence the function is not called yet
3. The function gets called in `print(f(1))` and the variable `x` takes `1` as its value
4. Finally the result function returns the computed value using `x`, and `a`, `b` and `c` (from `square_fun(1, 2, 3)`)

You can find additional info here => https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures

Comment: Indeed, simple solution!  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial


def square_fun(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x ** 2 + b * x + c


f = partial(square_fun, a=1, b=2, c=3)
print(f(1))
# should print 6
```